# mysql's current_timestamp for java derby

Tags: java, sql, mysql, derby

In MySQL I can easily set the default value of a timestamp field to be the current time

```
fieldname timestamp not null default current_timestamp
```

Does anyone know how to do the same thing in java derby?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work `fieldname TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: that was a stupid question, even the lowercase works... I just didn't try it out. Thanks